# Accessing result array size in chained call

Tags: ruby, method-chaining

I am trying to write a one-liner to create a hash from the output of the host-only interface listing of VirtualBox. It looks something like this

```
Name:            vboxnet0
GUID:            77777777-6666-4444-8888-020227202302
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.42.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
MediumType:      Ethernet
Status:          Up
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0

Name:            vboxnet1
GUID:            77777777-6666-4444-8888-020227202301
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       172.16.0.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:01
MediumType:      Ethernet
Status:          Up
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet1
```

I tried:

```
Hash[*`VBoxManage list hostonlyifs`.split("\n").reject(&:empty?).collect {|s| s.split(/:\ */)}.flatten(1)]
```

Result is:

```
=> {"Name"=>"vboxnet1", "GUID"=>"786f6276-656e-4174-8000-0a0027000001", "DHCP"=>"Disabled", "IPAddress"=>"172.16.0.1", "NetworkMask"=>"255.255.255.0", "IPV6Address"=>"IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength", "0"=> "HardwareAddress", "0a"=>"00", "27"=>"00", "00"=>"01", "MediumType"=>"Ethernet", "Status"=>"Up", "VBoxNetworkName"=>"HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet1"}
```

Pretty much what I wanted but only for the first interface. I was thinking: "Okay, slice the array into half and convert each half to a hash!".

My problem is how do I get the size of the Array returned by the flatten method and use it in the parameter of the slice method without assigning it to a variable and etc.?

I mean something like:

```
`VBoxManage list hostonlyifs`.split("\n").reject(&:empty?).collect {|s| s.split(/:\ */)}.flatten(1).slice(0..>>>how_to_access_result_object_of_flatten_here<<<.size/2)
```

I am not that experienced in Ruby so sorry if the question is just obvious, but I tried a lot of Googling to no avail.

EDIT: The regexp for `split` in the ?closure/lambda? passed to `collect` is not right, since it returns only one string(should be two for hash conversion to work) if after the colon there are only spaces which is the case for the line starting with `IPV6Address:` (not visible in the example). I changed it to `split(/:\ /)` and now it works. The space is needed because using only colon would also split the MAC address.

Comment: I don't understand the `No such file or directory` problem, I cannot produce it on my machine. The call to a program and getting its output is exactly what I want. For the splitting part see edit of the post.

Comment: I don't know why I thought the backticks were not intended--it's clear on second reading that they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is some special Ruby voodoo that I've never seen I'm pretty sure the simple answer is you can't.

However, the next best approach (instead of assigning the array to a variable) is to extend the `Array` class and write an extra method, like so:

```
class Array
  def flatten_and_slice
    flattened_result = self.flatten(1)
    self.slice(0..flattened_result.size/2)
  end
end
```

Then you just call your new method.

```
`VBoxManage list hostonlyifs`.split("\n").reject(&:empty?).collect {|s| s.split(/:\ */)}.flatten_and_slice
```

Comment: That would be some much appreciated voodoo for this problem, not sure how much sense it makes alltogether. I found the [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) method, which I could use to set an environment variable use it and remove it with another tap, but one has to know when to let go of things :) and maybe use Your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can just split the output by `^$` and take the interface you want:

```
text = `VBoxManage list hostonlyifs`
Hash[*text.split(/^$/)[0].split(/\n/).flat_map {|line| line.split(":", 2).map(&:strip) }]
```

`text.split(/^$/)[0]` splits the text on blank lines and takes the first interface. Then, we just take that text and parse it into a hash by splitting into individual lines, splitting into [key, value] pairs, and mapping it into a Hash. This gives output like:

```
{
                           "Name" => "vboxnet0",
                           "GUID" => "77777777-6666-4444-8888-020227202302",
                           "DHCP" => "Disabled",
                      "IPAddress" => "192.168.42.1",
                    "NetworkMask" => "255.255.255.0",
                    "IPV6Address" => "",
    "IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength" => "0",
                "HardwareAddress" => "0a:00:27:00:00:00",
                     "MediumType" => "Ethernet",
                         "Status" => "Up",
                "VBoxNetworkName" => "HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0"
}
```

If you want to generate an array of hashes, one for each interface, split the text, then map each chunk of text into a Hash:

```
text.split(/^$/).map {|chunk| Hash[*chunk.split(/\n/).flat_map {|line| line.split(":", 2).map(&:strip) }] }
```

Resulting in:

```
[
    [0] {
                               "Name" => "vboxnet0",
                               "GUID" => "77777777-6666-4444-8888-020227202302",
                               "DHCP" => "Disabled",
                          "IPAddress" => "192.168.42.1",
                        "NetworkMask" => "255.255.255.0",
                        "IPV6Address" => "",
        "IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength" => "0",
                    "HardwareAddress" => "0a:00:27:00:00:00",
                         "MediumType" => "Ethernet",
                             "Status" => "Up",
                    "VBoxNetworkName" => "HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0"
    },
    [1] {
                               "Name" => "vboxnet1",
                               "GUID" => "77777777-6666-4444-8888-020227202301",
                               "DHCP" => "Disabled",
                          "IPAddress" => "172.16.0.1",
                        "NetworkMask" => "255.255.255.0",
                        "IPV6Address" => "",
        "IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength" => "0",
                    "HardwareAddress" => "0a:00:27:00:00:01",
                         "MediumType" => "Ethernet",
                             "Status" => "Up",
                    "VBoxNetworkName" => "HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet1"
    }
]
```